# SQL Server 2014: Restore old backup

Tags: database, backup, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to restore an old database backup in SQL Server 2014, and I'm getting the error below:

[image]

How can I go through this?

I'm importing the backup in the follow way:

- Tasks -> Restore -> Database
- Select device option -> Pick up the .bak file
- At the options select Overwrite
- ok

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to restore a SQL Server 2000 database on SQL Server 2014. This is not supported.

You will need to restore your database on an instance of SQL Server 2005, 2008 or 2008 R2 first, then back it up from there, then restore the new backup on SQL Server 2014. [Microsoft explains this here how to on SQL Server 2012](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2012/06/15/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to jump that many versions from a SQL 2000 backup straight to 2014. It's just too much of a jump with too many changes to be made.

Restore it to SQL 2008 first, then back this up and then restore to 2014.

Here's some links to guides that should be able to help you;

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/sql-select-steps-migrate-sql-server-2000-sql-server-2014

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2012/06/15/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Is there an option "Reforce" in the options menu?

Comment: What are you expecting to see with a 'Reforce' option? I think you're over thinking this. The issue is that you're trying to jump between editions that were built 14 years apart. The architecure just isn't designed to be compatible that far apart. Because of this you'll have to jump to an intermediate version (e.g. 2008) to do what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all not, that you can restore your SQL Server database backups on a different version of SQL Server, but with one tiny restriction. You can restore your backups only upwards, it means that you can restore from SQL Serve 2005 to 2008 or from 2012 to 2014.

But it has to be admitted, there is no way of restoring your database backups from SQL Server 2012 to 2008. SQL Server has such restriction because every new version has modifications in the binary of the database and their storage.

Also, you can't jump forward two versions, for example, you cannot restore a database backups from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server version 2014 as you are trying.

As it has recommended above you need to restore in few steps. Firstly restore it on SQL Server 2005 or 2008. make a full backup and then restore it on SQL Server 2014.